# Safari disallow the use of certain @font-faces

Tags: macos, fonts, safari, font-faces

Is there a way for a user to not allow the use of certain @font-faces in the css of a Webpage? My first thought was using Safari's user style sheets but I don't know how I could over-ride certain fonts, perhaps the best would be based on the url in the @font-face attribute.

Slightly more in depth, My original problem is many of my favorite websites are slow to load because their custom @font-face is loading from google or amazon servers. If you don't live in an area where Google or Amazon have servers then you see most of the layout of a website without any text content. I know that the content is there, the HTML file has been downloaded, its just that the text is not rendering until the font-face has finished downloading. i'm experimenting to see if this would speed things up.

Comment: Followup: Would downloading the troublesome fonts and placing them in my Font-Book make things faster?